# Is there a way to convert the first of two or more consecutive div tags to a span tag

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to convert the first div of any consecutive div in an HTML to a span. An example of this is been below

```
<div><div>Hello</div></div>
```

The desired output for this should be

```
<span><div>Hello</div></span>
```

The thing I want to achieve is to write a function that receives the HTML body and then returns the formatted HTML body with the span replacing the necessary divs

Comment: What if there are <div><div><div>Hello</div></div></div>?

Comment: You could match the first `<div>` of two or more with `(?<!<div>)<div>(?=<div>)` where `(?<!<div>)` is a *negative lookbehind* and `(?=<div>)` is a *positive lookahead*.

Comment: Could you explain further, please? Probably with an example. For this scenario though all only one of the divs should remain and the rest turned to spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as pattern text which captures the text between div's.

```
<div>(.*)<\/div>
```

Use this as replacement text

```
<span>$1</span>
```

You can check here - https://regex101.com/r/02Rqj6/2

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean?

Comment: The first regex I mentioned is used to match the pattern you are looking for and then once it finds the match and captures the group, we use second text and use $1 to refer the captured group between span tags

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer and upvote it pls.

Comment: Can this be extended to the case of <div><div><div>Hello</div></div></div> where all the divs are turned to span except one?

Comment: `(?<=<div>)(<div>(?!<div>)([\w<>].*?)<\/div>)(?=<\/div>)` - you can try this. But since the it starts from inner most match and it will only have one match of that. Make sure to loop thru the same text until there is no match. Everytime u match the replacement text can be `<span>$2</span>`

Answer (score 0):

So the following code works for the example you have given.
The assumption here made is that  `<div><div><div>Hello</div></div></div>` will become `<span><div><div>Hello</div></div></span>`

```
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  console.log(divs.length)
  divs.forEach(function(item,index){
    
  //the div should be the only child node if it's nested like this
   if(item.childNodes.length == 1 && item.childNodes[0].nodeName == "DIV")      
    {
     var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
     span.innerHTML = item.innerHTML; 
     item.parentNode.replaceChild(span, item);
    }
  })
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txe48w5m/

Comment: The thing I want to write a function that receives the HTML body and then returns the formatted HTML body with the span replacing the necessary divs